# Load runner : String Array

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am unable to print the string array in the vuser_end section. For Eg, I am storing nearly 5 strings in array in "Action" section. I can display the array in the Action section. But i am unable to display the same in "End" section.

```
init()
char *pnum[100];
char *pchar[100];
char *paramValn;
char *paramValc;
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
int m;

action()
for(k=0;k<=5;k++)
    {
        paramValn = lr_eval_string("{p_num}");
        pnum[i] = paramValn;

        paramValc = lr_eval_string("{p_char}");
        pchar[i] = paramValc;

        i++;
    }

for(n=0;n<5;n++)
    {
        lr_output_message("String value: %d : %s",n,pnum[n]);
    }
```

Here p_num and p_char are parameters.

The output of this is :

```
Action1.c(18): String value: 0 : 12345
Action1.c(18): String value: 1 : 60091
Action1.c(18): String value: 2 : 76767
Action1.c(18): String value: 3 : 87878
Action1.c(18): String value: 4 : 12345

vuser_end()
{
     for(m=0;m<5;m++)
    {
        lr_output_message("String value in end: %d : %s",m,pnum[m]);
    }
    TE_wait_sync();
    lr_think_time(3);
    TE_type("<kF3>");
    TE_wait_sync();
    TE_type("<kF3>");
    TE_wait_sync();
    TE_type("<kF3>");
    lr_think_time(3);
    TE_type("<kEnter>"); return 0;
}
```

But when I use the same code in End section , I am unable to display :

Output is :

```
vuser_end.c(12): String value in end: 0 : Š
vuser_end.c(12): String value in end: 1 : –
vuser_end.c(12): String value in end: 2 : Ö
vuser_end.c(12): String value in end: 3 : ž
vuser_end.c(12): String value in end: 4 : vuser_end_Transaction
```

I know this is because of memory issue. Any pointers is helpful.

Comment: What does `lr_eval_string` do? What does it return?

Comment: It just reads the string which is being passed. Example : paramValn = lr_eval_string("{p_num}"); Here paramValn is a character variable which gets data of "p-num" which is a parameter being passed. It can contain something like abcd or anything that is passed as value

Comment: But what does it *do*? Please show us *the code*. Preferably please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: And what is `vuser_end`? Is it a function? Something else? Is it using the same `pnum` variable? What do you mean by "sections"? Without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is going to be really hard if not impossible to help you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : It just is used to save the variable. The problem here is with teh array. As can be seen from my original post, the array has right data in the "action section - for loop with "n" as variable. But the same array is not displayed in END section - for loop with "m" as variable.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Is `char *pnum[100]` a global variable? What does `init()`-statement mean? Please provide something that comiples.

Comment: vuser_end is "END" section in loadrunner. I just depicted that the code is from END section

Comment: The main point of my comments are: Are you sure that `pnum` is ***the same variable*** in all "sections" and functions?

Comment: pnum is an array, which gets data from lr_save_string("{p_num}"). p_num is a parametrization

Comment: to some programmer dude....this is loadrunner.  It is an ANSI C environment used to build code which represents the actions of a user for performance testing stuff.   Action(), vuser_[init|end]() are functions.   Action is the iterated section.  Vuser_init() runs once at the beginning of the test, Vuser_end() once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

1. char *pnum[100] - is a local variable for vuser_init.c.
2. Declare char *pnum[] as a global variable in globals.h file.
3. Please post your answer after the above change.